# UEFI Bootable Gparted USB Bootable Drive

Tags: usb, boot, uefi

I can't seem to get the latest Gparted to boot on my UEFI laptops.  I've tried creating the usb disk via Unetbootin, Lili, Rufus and while it will boot on non-secure laptops, it won't on my URFI enabled ones.

I've been able to successfully boot a UEFI Clonezilla usb disk to my UEFI laptops with the same flash drive and followed the same exact steps with the Gparted iso to no avail.  I also made sure to format the usb disk before putting  the Gparted image on it.

From what I can tell, the Gparted iso doesn't actually support UEFI booting yet.    Can anyone confirm that they've booted Gparted on a secure boot UEFI computer?

Thanks!

Jerome

Answer (score 3):

So, it turns out I was right.  The ISO image on the latest GParted doesn't work properly for UEFI boot by default.  I've outlined how to fix it, but it requires a UEFI Clonezilla image.

- Run Unetbootin.exe as an admin and create the latest version of GParted image on a flash drive per the norm
- Copy the \boot\ directory from a clonezilla ISO/configured flash drive to the root of the newly created GParted flash drive
- Copy the following files found in \EFI\boot\ (ignore the x86_64-efi folder) to the same directory on the newly created GParted flsh drive:
  bootia32.efi
  bootx64.efi
  grubx64.efi
  unicode.pf2

If you get a prompt from UNbootin asking to overwrite the syslinux\menu.c32 file, click No.  Or if you get an error when booting from the flash drive regarding the syslinux\menu.c32 file, overwrite that from a clonezilla ISO too.

Your welcome.

Jerome